# spreadsheet script/nag email runs fine manually or minute timer, but not with day timer

Tags: google-apps-script

This is a puzzler.  I have a google spreadsheet.  It's mean to allow online eval of lectures.  Residents log in to the associated form, and fill it out.

Accompanying it is a "nag" function - a second sheet checks for their name, keeps track if they have submitted or not yet, and if not it sends a nag email after a certain time (3 days) has elapsed.

The script runs fine it I do it manually. Also if I use a minute timer (i.e., run every 10 minutes).

But when I set up the script for what I want - to check once a day, it doesn't run and I get the following error report:

Invalid email: #N/A

This is particularly odd as I have other similar functions running for other spreadsheets and they have always worked.

The only thing I can think of that is different here is I have several similar scripts running (one sheet for each week).  I tried changing the function name to something unique, also changed the spreadsheet call to openById, and the sheet variable to getSheetByName just in case the multiple similar scripts were somehow confusing each other.  No diff.

The link to a copy of the spreadsheet is here https://docs.google.com/a/brown.edu/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkP6szc0nsS2dEItLXEwdjVsWUFpOTdjZUdtTlo4cGc#gid=0

and I'm attaching the script in the following (you'll note I added error reporting, but it doesn't add much).  The data variables borrow from the tutorial, and that tutorial snippet has always worked fine for me.

any insight would be appreciated.

Code:

```
var SEMINAR_FORM_URL = "http://med.brown.edu/DPHB/training/psychiatry_general/secure/seminarevals/seminar_evals.html";
var YES = "YES";
var DISTRIBUTE = "robert_boland_1@brown.edu,robertboland11@gmail.com"; 

//This function sends out a nag to do the seminar evals including a link to the seminar form
//This is allowed when sheet 2 says "YES" to "Nag?"  
//Should not check more than once daily or will keep sending out and should be triggered AFTER the checkCoverageSubmit. 

function sendNag() {  
  try {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AkP6szc0nsS2dDkwQTE0OVlPeWM5ZlJIenVKLU1pVVE");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var startRow = 2

  // getRowsData was reused from Reading Spreadsheet Data using JavaScript Objects tutorial
  var data = getRowsData(sheet);

  // For every Seminar report row
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    row.rowNumber = i + 2;    
    if (row.nag==YES) {   //sends the nag message below
     var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
    + "<P> THIS IS A REMINDER MESSAGE:"
    + "<P> For "  + row.name         
    + "<P> You still need to complete your seminar evaluations for" 
    + "<P> the seminars done on "+ row.dateOfSeminar
    + "<P>" 
    + "<P> It has been "+ row.daysElapsed + " days since the seminar." 
    + "<P>"     
    + '<P><b> Please fill out the evaluations.  You can find links to the evalutions on <A HREF="' + SEMINAR_FORM_URL + '"><b>HERE.</b></A>  Do this now!</b>.' 
    + "<P>"
    + "<P>" 
    + "<P>" 
    + "<P>--------------------------------------------------------"
    + "<P> <i>You are receiving this message because our records report that you have yet to complete a required seminar evaluations. </i>"
    + "<P> If you think this remind was sent in error, please <a href='mailto:robert_boland_1@brown.edu'><b>contact me</b></a> to prevent further nagging!"    
    + "<P>"     
    + "<P>_______________________________________________________________________________"
    + "</HTML></BODY>";
      if(row.name){  
      MailApp.sendEmail(row.name, "Reminder: Please complete your seminar evals!", "", {cc:DISTRIBUTE,htmlBody: message});
      } SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
    } 
  }   

  } catch (e) {    
    MailApp.sendEmail("robert_boland_1@brown.edu", "Error report", e.message); 
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Code reused from Reading Spreadsheet Data using JavaScript Objects tutorial //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to all the cells except those in the first row
//       or all the cells below columnHeadersRowIndex (if defined).
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range; 
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  var headersIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range ? range.getRowIndex() - 1 : 1;
  var dataRange = range || 
    sheet.getRange(headersIndex + 1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows() - headersIndex, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var numColumns = dataRange.getEndColumn() - dataRange.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(headersIndex, dataRange.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(dataRange.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

// For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data. Names of
// object fields are defined in keys.
// Arguments:
//   - data: JavaScript 2d array
//   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create
function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var object = {};
    var hasData = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
      var cellData = data[i][j];
      if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
        continue;
      }
      object[keys[j]] = cellData;
      hasData = true;
    }
    if (hasData) {
      objects.push(object);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

// Returns an Array of normalized Strings. 
// Empty Strings are returned for all Strings that could not be successfully normalized.
// Arguments:
//   - headers: Array of Strings to normalize
function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    keys.push(normalizeHeader(headers[i]));
  }
  return keys;
}

// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
      continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return key;
}

// Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
// Arguments:
//   - cellData: string
function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}

// Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise.
function isAlnum(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}

// Returns true if the character char is a digit, false otherwise.
function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}
```

Comment: Are you using custom functions or slow functions in the spreadsheet? As these will often return  #N/A if the spreadsheet has not been opened for a while (10 mins or so when I last checked). But it does look like a divide and conquer type problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please parse your error into the following function so we can have more info, e.g. the line number.

```js
/**
 * Parse errors stacktrace into a readable format.
 * This function never throws an error, so you don't need to try-catch it.
 * If the error cannot be processed, it will just return it silently.
 * @return {string} The error toString plus its stacktrack broke into multiple lines
 * @param {Error} e The error to be processed
 */
function parseErr(e) {
  try {
    var ret;
    if( e !== undefined && e !== null && e.stack && e.toString ) {
      ret = e.toString()+' \nStacktrace: \n';
      var stack = e.stack.replace(/\n/g,'').match(/:\d+( \([^\)]+\))?/g);
      for( var i in stack )
        ret += stack[i].replace(/[\(\):]/g,'').split(/ /).reverse().join(':') + ' \n';
    } else if( typeof(e) === 'object' )
      ret = inspect(ret);
    else
      ret = ''+e;
    return ret;
  } catch(suppress) {
    return ''+e;
  }
}

/**
 * Inspect an object properties and returns a nicely formatted string
 * Good to be logged or sent via email.
 * @return {string} inspection of the object's iterable elements
 * @param {*} o object to be inspected
 * @param {number=} optMaxLevel optional max level that function should go deep in the object
 *     Important to avoid infinite loops on recursive objects. Defaults to 4
 */
function inspect(o,optMaxLevel) {
  if( optMaxLevel === undefined )
    optMaxLevel = 4; //default inspect level
  else if( optMaxLevel < 1 )
    return '\n> maximum level must be equal to or greater than 1 (one)';
  if( o === null || o === undefined )
    return '\n> '+o;
  else {
    var tof = function(v) {
      try { return typeof(v); } //I don't now why typeof is throwing errors on arrays
      catch(e) { return 'object'; } //so I'm just defaulting to object
    };
    var ret = function innerInspect(o,maxLevel,level) {
      var msg = '';
      if( level.length > maxLevel ) {
        for( var i in o )
          msg += i+',';
        msg = '\n'+level+msg.substring(0,msg.length-1); //remove last comma
      } else {
        for( var i in o ) {
          var t = tof(o[i]);
          msg += '\n'+level+i+' :: '+t;
          try {
            if( t == 'object' && o[i] )
              msg += innerInspect(o[i],maxLevel,'>'+level);
            else if( t != 'function' )
              msg += ' = "'+o[i]+'"';
          } catch(e) {
            msg += '\n>'+level+e.message;
          }
        }
        if( msg == '' )
          msg = ' = "'+o.toString()+'"';
      }
      return msg;
    }(o,optMaxLevel+1,'> ');
    return ret.substring(0,2) == ' =' ? '\n> '+tof(o)+ret : ret;
  }
}
```

Instead of mailing yourself just `e.message` send the parsed stack or even better, also add some values of the current variables, e.g.:

```js
var moreInfo = inspect({i:i, row:row}) + '\n' + parseErr(e);
MailApp.sendEmail("yourself@etc", "Error report", moreInfo);
```

Comment: well, thanks @Henrique Abreu, but I actually don't know where to incorporate the above.  You may be assuming I know more than I actually do...

Comment: Replace your `MailApp` line inside your `catch` clause with those two lines I pasted after the functions as an usage example.

Comment: Henrique, you are amazing helpful, thanks!  I finally figured out the problem - not in the script at all, it was in the spreadsheet.  the emails being used to send were actually referenced from another spreadsheet (using the importrange command).  apparently when the sheets are closed and I'm using a timer it cannot open multiple sheets?  Anyhow, when I got rid of the importrange thing and just wrote in the emails manually, it worked fine (shame though - the personnel change and it would be nice to have one master sheet that other sheets can reference.  Alas.).  Thanks all again.

Comment: I'm glad I helped. But this problem was nailed by @eddyparkinson on the first comment. `importRange` is a "slow function".